# Expressing (x^3)/1000 - 100*x^2 - 100*x + 3 in big theta notation

Tags: big-o

Hello can somebody help me in expressing `(x^3)/1000 - 100*x^2 - 100*x + 3` in big theta notation. It looks like of `x^3` to me, but obviously at `x = 0` obviously this polynomial gives a value of 3. Multiplying `x^3` by any constant won't help at all. Is there a standard way to approach such kind of problem?

Comment: How is this programming related? try http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its programming related because it has to do with determining algorithm efficiency. Its called worst-case analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't **remain** below 3.
Nor does it, eventually, remain below c*x, or c*x^2 for any constant c. So it's definitely Θ(x^3).

Comment: Thanks got it...it eventually gets to be of x^3 for some large value of x, what that value be doesn't matter :)